# How many CPU cores can Firefox Quantum utilize?

Tags: firefox, javascript, multi-core, multi-threaded, firefox-quantum

I have a webapp that is very CPU intensive (multiple nested loops running over large dataset). I could run it in one Firefox tab or distribute the load across multiple tabs (if that's better).

I was thinking of building a new computer and saw that processors now have up to 20+ cores... Would Firefox Quantum be able to take advantage of them all? Can firefox run each tab in a separate core? Is that controlled by Firefox or by the OS?